# Modelling habitat heterogeneity in space: R function

Tags: r, kernel-density, habitat-modeling

I'm working on spatial landscape simulations and I would like to simulate a landscape where habitat quality varies in space.

I did already some simulations assuming a landscape with higher habitat amount in the middle and lower habitat amount on the borders of the landscape. In this case I used the `gaussian.kernel` function in the `SpatialEco` R package.

Now, I would like to simulate a landscape with higher habitat amount in the borders and lower habitat amount in the middle.

My idea was to use a bivariate truncated bimodal distribution (for instance beta distribution, with U-shape). But I do not know how.
Do you have any suggestion?

I work in R and I prefer to do it in-there.

Comment: If `Z` is your raster with a peak in the middle, could you use `max(Z)-Z` which would produce a raster with a dip to zero in the middle?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this it increase the habitat quality values in the raster, while I wanted to have the same total habitat quality amount across landscape.

Comment: Then multiply the raster by a constant to scale the sum to the total you want?